# Action Script 3 (flex) attach and stream camera in different qualities (multiply modes)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, camera, resolution, flex4.5

I need to attach my camera to the VideoDisplay, for example with 640x480 resolution, and stream it to the NetStream in 320x240 resolution. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
cam.setMode(320, 240, 15);

var video:Video = new Video(640, 480);
//video.attachCamera(cam);
ns.attachCamera(cam);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer!
In this way the camera is just attached to the 640x480 video, with 320x240 quality, so we will get bad quality of video.
i think the answer is to record camera in 640x480 into temporary stream, that will be decoded into two streams, for our video in 640x480 quality, and for stream in 320x240 quality. But i have no idea how to decode it into two streams...